# Masters admission while still enrolled on another course

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am a little concerned and need your help. I am applying for a master program abroad. However, I am enrolled in another master program and still have two semesters to finish. I am not sure what to say on my CV: should I mention that I have completed two semesters and want to quit it or should I not say anything about it?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand why you are applying for another program if you still have two semesters to finish on your current one.

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to bail from one masters program does not suggest you will successfully complete another. Or that you were thoughtful in choosing the first masters program. Plenty of people out there with two masters degrees.

If you quit, don't say anything about it. If you get asked, say you took some courses but decided it wasn't for you. Unless it's extremely expensive, or you need to quit right now, keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are currently enrolled in a program, you should list it on your CV. At some point you will usually have to provide information on your former education anyway.

In the CV itself you do not have to say anything about wanting to quit, but in the application letter you should explain carefully why you are choosing to apply for another program even though you still did not finish your first master degree. You want to avoid the impression that you are a "quitter" who does not finish things he/she signed up for.